# Duplicate Images with different Paths

Tags: android, image, path, duplicates, gallery

In my android application, i am using an intent with **EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE**, to select from gallery a group or pictures, the selected pictures will then be shown in a **RecyclerView** to the user, usually i no problems happen an functionality is as intended, but from time to time, when the **RecyclerView** pictures are loaded, an image appears twice, and when this happens, it takes the place of another image. Following is the code i use for the intent to go to gallery, as well as the **OnActivityResult** method and related methods.

**GalleryIntent**:

```
private void galleryIntent()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);//
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),SELECT_FILE);
}
```

**OnActivityResult**:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    int dataCount=0;
    Uri tempUri;
    List<Uri> multiUri=null;

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        if(data!=null){
            if(data.getClipData()==null){
                //Solo una foto seleccionada
                onSelectFromGalleryResults(data.getData());
            }else{
                //Mas de una foto seleccionada
                dataCount=data.getClipData().getItemCount();
                multiUri=new ArrayList<>();

                for(int y=0; y<dataCount;y++){
                    tempUri=data.getClipData().getItemAt(y).getUri();
                    multiUri.add(tempUri);
                }
                onSelectFromGalleryMultiResults(multiUri);

            }
        }

    }
}
```

From these i find it necessary for clarity's sake just in case to add that, when filling the **RecyclerView**, i pass to the adapter a List of the **Real Paths** of these pictures, and i obtain these real paths with the following code, by giving it the corresponding **URI** of the picture:

```
public class PathUtil {
/*
 * Gets the file path of the given Uri.
 */
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public static String getPath(Context context, Uri uri) throws URISyntaxException {
    final boolean needToCheckUri = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19;
    String selection = null;
    String[] selectionArgs = null;
    // Uri is different in versions after KITKAT (Android 4.4), we need to
    // deal with different Uris.
    if (needToCheckUri && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context.getApplicationContext(), uri)) {
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
        } else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));
        } else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                uri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }
            selection = "_id=?";
            selectionArgs = new String[]{ split[1] };
        }
    }
    if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    } else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }
    return null;
}


/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
 */
public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
 */
public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
 */
public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}
```

}

And then, in the adapter, i use these paths to load the **Pictures** and then fill the **RecyclerView** (i do it this way because there is a need to retrieve these pictures in a later part of the application)

Finally, this is the method i use to get the bitmap given the real path:

```
public static Bitmap getSampleBitmapFromFile(String bitmapFilePath, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) throws FileNotFoundException {
    // calculating image size
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(new File(bitmapFilePath)), null, options);

    int scale = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize = scale;

    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(new File(bitmapFilePath)), null, o2);

}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Alto y ancho original de la imagen
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        //Calculo de relacion entre ancho y alto para obtener una escala apropiada
        final int heightRatio = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);
        final int widthRatio = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);

        // EScoger la relacion mas pequeña en inSamplesize, esto garantiza el tamaño correcto deseado
        inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

And well, as i already mentioned, everything works fine most of the time, but in certain tests, even with different paths they load the same image, if anything else might be required of my part as additional info so as to solve this issue i will try to edit it in too.

Edit:
This is the OnSelectFromGalleryResults method, as well as the MultiResults, they are basically the same. Also setup image and multi image are basically the same too

```
 private void onSelectFromGalleryResults(Uri fotoUri) {

    if (fotoUri!=null){


        String filePath="";
        try {
            filePath= PathUtil.getPath(getActivity(),fotoUri);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Se agrega a la lista de fotos para el adaptador
        setupImage(filePath);

    }else {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Archivo no encontrado.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}


public void onSelectFromGalleryMultiResults(List<Uri> myImagesUris){

    List<String> multiRealPaths=new ArrayList<>();

    if(myImagesUris==null)
        return;

    for(int h=0; h<myImagesUris.size();h++){
        if (myImagesUris.get(h)!=null){
            String filePath="";
            try {
                filePath= PathUtil.getPath(getActivity(),myImagesUris.get(h));
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                //Se agrega a la lista de fotos tomadas
                multiRealPaths.add(filePath);
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Archivo no encontrado.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    }


    setupMultiImage(multiRealPaths);

}

private void setupMultiImage(List<String> realPaths) {

    mCallBack.PhotoSetPhotoInspection(true);
    takenUris.addAll(realPaths);
    photosTakenCounter=takenUris.size();
    photosTaken.clear();
    photosTaken.addAll(takenUris);

    if(gVA==null){
        gVA= new GridViewAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.grid_item_layout, photosTaken);
        gV.setAdapter(gVA);
        gVA.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }else{
        gVA.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    //Se actualiza la lista de imagenes en la actividad controladora
    mCallBack.sendPhotoPaths(takenUris);

}
```

Comment: you'll need to show what you are doing with onSelectFromGalleryResults() and onSelectFromGalleryMultiResults()

Comment: alright, give me a sec

Comment: Also it dawned on me if i should have use getContext() instead of getActivity and if that might be a possible source of the problem, the methods are inside a fragment